# In lex.yy.c what do the lookup tables stand for?

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

I'm digging through a lexer built with flex ([here](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius/blob/6d135a686a74376495a7a6f55d3d67df54186f83/gramtools/mkdfa/mkfa-1.44-flex/lex.yy.c) to be precise) and am trying to understand what is happening. Never having looked at C, I've given up trying to find the equivalent to [understand parsers made with Bison](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~spopuri/cparser.html), so I'm hoping to just get some basic info here, starting with what do the lookup tables in lex.yy.c contain:

```
static yyconst short int yy_accept[33] =
{   0,
    0,    0,   15,   13,   12,   10,    7,   13,   13,    8,
    2,    9,   13,    3,    4,    0,   11,    0,    0,    2,
    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    5,
    6,    0
} ;

static yyconst int yy_ec[256] =
{   0,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    2,    3,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    2,    4,    1,    5,    1,    6,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    7,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    8,    8,    8,
    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    9,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,   10,   11,    8,    8,    8,   12,    8,
   13,    8,   14,    8,    8,    8,    8,   15,   16,    8,
    8,   17,   18,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    8,    1,    8,    8,    8,    8,

    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,
    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,    8,
    8,    8,   19,    1,   20,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,

    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1
} ;

static yyconst int yy_meta[21] =
{   0,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    2,    1,    1,
    2,    2,    2,    2,    2,    2,    2,    2,    1,    1
} ;

static yyconst short int yy_base[36] =
{   0,
    0,    0,   39,   40,   40,   40,   40,   35,   10,   40,
    0,   40,    0,   40,   40,   34,   40,   18,   22,    0,
    0,   16,   18,   18,   15,   17,   12,   13,   15,   40,
   40,   40,   24,   21,   20
} ;

static yyconst short int yy_def[36] =
{   0,
   32,    1,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   33,   32,   32,
   34,   32,   35,   32,   32,   33,   32,   32,   32,   34,
   35,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,
   32,    0,   32,   32,   32
} ;

static yyconst short int yy_nxt[61] =
{   0,
    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,   11,   12,   13,
   11,   11,   11,   11,   11,   11,   11,   11,   14,   15,
   18,   21,   20,   19,   16,   16,   31,   30,   29,   28,
   27,   26,   25,   24,   23,   22,   17,   17,   32,    3,
   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,
   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32
} ;

static yyconst short int yy_chk[61] =
{   0,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
    9,   35,   34,    9,   33,   33,   29,   28,   27,   26,
   25,   24,   23,   22,   19,   18,   16,    8,    3,   32,
   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,
   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32,   32
} ;
```

Any reference to a good explanation of a generated lex.yy.c is of course also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: These are data to describe the (finite) automaton used for analysis. Read about "finite automata", for example this: http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs211/ho/node6.html

Comment: I doubt anyone can tell you *specifically* what these tables mean without studying (or already knowing) the Flex source.  *Generally* they describe the behavior of a finite state machine with which the generated lexer function will process input.  You might get some clues by running Flex with the `-v` / `--verbose` option and comparing the results to the tables.

Comment: The precise meaning of the tables varies depending on the table compression type (see option `-C`).

Comment: thanks for the tips. I will have a look

Comment: "Never having looked at C" -- Flex-generated tables is probably not the easiest way to learn C...

Comment: These tables portray a state machine for matching text. your lexer starts at state 0, and depending on what character they read next they transition to another state, when they end up at an accepting state they can run one of the actions specified in your flex script. The main tables are yy_accept which will take a state and return which action to run in the .l script, and yy_nxt, which given a state and  a character will tell you which state to go to next, if it returns 0, then you need to look up which action to run in the yy_accept table. The rest of the tables are related to compression.

Answer (score 3):

*(Compiling the comments to an answer, only to make a Q/A pair)*.

These are data to describe the "(finite) automaton" or "finite state machine" used to implement the text analysis described by the lexer generation-input/config files.

Read about "finite automata", for example this:   http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs211/ho/node6.html

Generally they describe the behavior of a finite state machine with which the generated lexer function will process input. You might get some clues by running Flex with the -v / --verbose option and comparing the results to the tables.

The precise meaning of the tables varies depending on the table compression type (see option -C).

I (John Bollinger, but probably agreed by most) doubt anyone can tell you specifically what these tables mean without studying (or already knowing) the Flex source. It is more or less the core idea of a generated lexer to protect the user from needing to know these details.

Comment: Respectfully quoting you @Jean-Baptiste with some glue.

Comment: Respectfully quoting you @John Bollinger with some glue.

Comment: Respectfully quoting you @rici with some glue.

Comment: Hi Yunnosch. It is a good idea to post an update from an OP where they have incorrectly edited their answer into their question. However for comments on an off-topic question, I wouldn't bother - the question may be deleted in the future anyway.

Comment: Thanks @halfer. But I can assume that the only disadvantage is my effort being lost. I.e. I do not annoy or hurt anybody?

Comment: I believe that upvoted posts make it harder to delete a question, so it might be a problem in general. The question doesn't look terrible in this case, so there is unlikely to be a rush to have it deleted, but it's worth considering the point in general, especially if the Q is obviously off-topic.

Comment: If the answer gets upvoted (inspite of my "copy only" notice) then I believe it  is good enough to not be deleted. Should I ever get more than 50 reputation this way, I promise to make a bounty and hand it over to the original author, if he notices and notifies me. If that is not against any rule, I know that "reputation traficking" is not good, but consider this different.

Comment: I am not worried about you getting a bit of extra rep, that is fine. I am giving you the community view of the impact of answering off-topic questions, which is intended to be helpful `:-)`.

Comment: Ah, good point, I will be more careful with offtopic questions. Thanks for alerting me.

Comment: Thanks. To be fair, sometimes things are marked as O/T even though it was not clear it was going to be put on hold. When that happens, don't worry about it.